# How do you find the first N prime numbers in python?

Tags: python, primes

I am pretty new to python, so I don't fully understand how to use loops. I am currently working on a piece of code that I have to find the first N prime numbers.
The result that is desired is if you input 5, it outputs 2, 3, 5, 7, and 11, but no matter what I input for 'max', the output always ends up being 2 and 3. Is there a way to improve this?

```
max=int(input("How many prime numbers do you want: "))
min=2
while(min<=(max)):
  for c in range(2, min):
    if min%c==0:
      break
  else:
    print min
    min=min+1
```

Comment: You don't really want 10 prime numbers then, just the prime numbers between 2 and 10.

Comment: This is a side comment. If you are new to Python I would strongly recommend jumping on 3.x Python (3.6 is stable release) as 2.7 will be deprecated in a few years.

Comment: Note that `min` and `max` are builtin functions of Python. You should avoid using these names for your variables, as their values would replace the original function. Trying to execute `min(2, 3)` after your code would cause a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only increment `min` in the `else` block, i.e., if `min % c` is nonzero for all `c`, i.e., if `min` is prime.  This means that the code won't be able to move past any composite numbers.  You can fix this by unindenting `min=min+1` one level so that it lines up with the `for` and `else`.

Answer (score 2):

```
number = int(input("Prime numbers between 2 and "))
for num in range(2,number + 1):
       if num > 1:
            for i in range(2,num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                     break
            else:
                print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Get the nth prime number entry. Iterate through each natural numbers for prime number and append the prime number to a list. Terminate the program when length of a list satisfies the user nth prime number entry.

```
# Get the number of prime numbers entry.
try:
    enterNumber = int(input("List of nth prime numbers: "))
except:
    print("The entry MUST be an integer.")
    exit()
startNumber = 1
primeList = []
while True:
    # Check for the entry to greater than zero.
    if enterNumber <= 0:
        print("The entry MUST be greater than zero.")
        break
    # Check each number from 1 for prime unless prime number entry is satisfied.
    if startNumber > 1:
        for i in range(2,startNumber):
            if (startNumber % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            primeList.append(startNumber)
    if (len(primeList) == enterNumber):
        print(primeList)
        break
    else:
        startNumber = startNumber + 1
        continue
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Pramit! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand :)

Comment: Solution: Get the nth prime number entry. Iterate through each natural numbers for prime number and append the prime number to a list. Terminate the program when length of a list satisfies the user nth prime number entry.

Comment: @Pramit I was looking for something like this to use in my program (not so fluent in python). Works great! However I think it can be improved by replacing this:       # for i in range(2,startNumber):
       #     if (startNumber % i) == 0:
        for i in range(0,len(primeList)-1):
            if (startNumber % primeList[i]) == 0:

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you prime numbers between 3 to N, where N is the input from user:

```py
number = int(input("Prime numbers between 2, 3 and ")) 
for i in range(2,number):
    for j in range(2,int(i/2)+1):
        if i%j==0:
            break
        elif j==int(i/2):
            print(i)
```

You can see to check a number i to be prime you only have to check its divisibility with numbers till n/2.

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
n = int(input("First N prime number, N ? "))
p = [2]
c = 2

while len(p) < n:
    j = 0
    c += 1
    while j < len(p):
        if c % p[j] == 0:
            break
        elif j == len(p) - 1:
            p.append(c)
        j += 1
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Check the below code, am sure it works!

```
N = int(input('Enter the number: ')
i=1
count=0
while(count<N):
      for x in range(i,i+1):
          c=0
          for y in range(1,x+1):
              if(x%y==0):
                 c=c+1
          if(c==2):
             print(x)
             count=count+1
      i=i+1
```